# Can we pass the created Stateful widget to another dart file and add that widget as body along with setState?

Tags: flutter

Can we pass the stateful widget created in one dart file to another dart file along with the setState changes and render that widget as the body in another stateful dart file.
Actually i am able to get the body but my setState is not working.

i want to pass the stateful widget(ie widget with dropdownbutton) to another page and my setState should work and i should be able to capture the data.

Comment: Question is not clear, what exactly you want to do. can you add some code?

Comment: did you managed to fix

Comment: i was not able to pass, but i just re used the code again. yet to find solution. Basically i want to create a widgets and use them in different files.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call the parent method, you can use state up. (Give call back to parent).
and if you want to call child method from a parent you can use `GlobalKey`.